# Sort List Comparing with String Array

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have an object list and a string array as below. How can I sort my object list according to my array? Is it possible to do with java comparator and collection.sort() ?

Grade Object

```
Class Grade{
   private Long keyId;
   private String gradeName;
   private int classCount;
}
```

Grade List

```
 List<Grades> grades= new ArrayList<>();
```

String Array

```
String[] gradeOrder= {"year 1", "year 2", "year 3", "year 4"};
```

Comment: The easy solution is to have the `Grades` object implement `Comparable` then you can simply use `Collections.sort(grades, yourCustomComparator);` where `Comparator<Grades> yourCustomComparator = (Grades g1, Grades g2) -> g1.gradeName.compareTo( g2.gradeName);`. This will use normal string sorting which thankfully we can use for your list because year 1 to year 4 are all in order already.

Comment: @sorifiend what if array like below ?
String[] gradeOrder= {"year 3", "year 2", "year 1", "year 4"};

Comment: Then your code could get messy fast and I would encourage you use an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) that represents a varue that works with a comparator for example `String YEAR_3 = "sort_1";` and `String YEAR_2 = "sort_2";` Or map the whole list and use that as your Comparator

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<>();
// add Grade instances to grades
String[] gradeOrder = {"year 1", "year 2", "year 3", "year 4"};
Map<String, Integer> gradeMap = IntStream.range(0, gradeOrder.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> gradeOrder[i], Function.identity()));

Collections.sort(grades,
    Comparator.comparing(grade -> gradeMap.get(grade.getGradeName())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List.sort(Comparator<? super E> c)`, provide a custom Comparator which contains an order structure (your gradeOrder array), or implement `equals()` method for your `Grade` class for more convinent comparing (but you may lost custom order ability by providing a certain order structure).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

You may want to try some library like lombok, which has a `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation to auto generate these methods for you class.

https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode